# Laravelが使うphpの指定方法

Tags: php, windows, laravel

ローカルpcでlaravelのサイトを作って動かしています。
phpのバージョンを上げて新しい機能が使いたいので、現在のphpを残して更に上のバージョンをインストールするつもりなのですが、laravelはどのphpを使うかをどうやって判断しているのでしょうか。
どのように紐づいているのでしょうか。

laravelプロジェクト内をphpのディレクトリ名でいろいろ検索してみたのですが、引っかかりませんでした。

OSはwindowsでとくにサーバーアプリやhomestead等は使っていません。
phpのサーバー機能を使っています。
(追記：実際にはphp artisan serveコマンドを使用)
インストールしてあるディレクトリは `c:\abc\php7.2` といった感じです。

新しいphpを入れたときにそちらを使うような指定方法はあるのでしょうか。

Comment: ここでいう「phpのサーバー機能」とは[ビルトインサーバー](https://www.php.net/manual/ja/features.commandline.webserver.php)を指しますか？

Comment: はい、その通りです。

Comment: php artisan serveで起動しています。

Comment: それはlaravelのサーバー機能ですね。PHP標準のではないです。質問もそのように編集して追記してください

Comment: 確かに書き方が正確じゃないどころか違った方向の回答をもらう可能性もありますね。追記しました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel に限らず、単に `php` とコマンドを呼び出した時に PHP のインストール先を指定するには、環境変数 PATH に設定しておく必要があります。

Windows 10 の場合には、以下の手順で環境変数の確認・変更が可能です。

**環境変数の確認・設定手順:**

- スタートメニュー → 「Windows システムツール」 → 「コントロールパネル」
- 「システムとセキュリティ」 → 「システム」
- 画面右側にある「システムの詳細設定」をクリック
- 「システムのプロパティ」ダイアログが開いたら「詳細設定」タブの「環境変数 ... 」をクリック
- 「システム環境変数」の一覧から変数が "Path" を探して「編集 ...」をクリック
- 一覧に PHP のインストール先が含まれているか確認

  - 別のバージョンをデフォルトとして認識させたい場合は、ここでインストール先の指定を変更する
  - 環境変数の設定を変更した後には、Windows を念のため再起動する

**参考:**
[PHPのPATHを設定する | Let'sプログラミング](https://www.javadrive.jp/php/install/index3.html#section2)

Comment: 助かりました。ありがとうございます。やっぱりlaravelプロジェクトごとの指定はできないのでしょうか。もしそうならhomesteadやvagrantやdockerが重宝されている理由ってこういうこともあるからなんですね。

Comment: ビルトインサーバーは1リクエストしか同時にさばけないため実用的ではなく、本番環境と同じにしようと思うと nginx と php-fpm という構成になることが多いです。こうなるとローカル環境をたくさん汚す必要性が出てくるので、脳死で docker を使うのが最もラクで一般的になっています。

Comment: いろいろ面倒くさいことを経ての、自由に作ったり捨てたりそしてpcを汚さずに済む環境構築ということなんですね。ありがとうございます。勉強になりました。