# rpy2に関して、Rのディレクトリの場所をどのように特定しているのでしょうか

Tags: python, r, jupyter-notebook

<環境>
os:windows10
実行環境:anaconda3 - jupyter notebook
主要ライブラリ:rpy2 3.7

〈本文〉
pythonでRを使用するためのrpy2というライブラリについて質問です。python環境下でrpy2を利用してRを使用することに成功しました。
一つ疑問なのですが、タイトルにもあるとおり、rpy2はどのようにしてRのディレクトリの特定をしているのでしょうか。例えば、Rのディレクトリの場所を移動させた場合、rpy2は機能しなくなるのでしょうか。
また、rpy2が参照しているRのディレクトリへのPATHを表示させる方法はありますでしょうか。

〈補足〉
実はR本体をインストールする際に、公式のRとanaconda-navigatorを使用してconda環境下のRの両方を以前インストールしました。そして、新しくRのライブラリ(以下Xとする)をconda環境下でインストールしてrpy2を利用しpython環境下で使用しようと試みたところXが見つかりませんでしたというエラーを検出しました。
そこで、Xを、「conda環境のディレクトリ」から「R公式からRのライブラリが格納されているディレクトリ」に、ドラッグ＆ドロップで移動させたところ、うまく行きました。
つまり、rpy2が参照していたのはR公式からインストールしていたRでした。

Comment: この辺の記事が参考になるかもしれません。[Using rpy2: cannot find R package that is installed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67028334/9014308), [R, Python: install packages on rpy2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11561258/9014308), [Rpy2 can't find my R libraries on install](https://pretagteam.com/question/rpy2-cant-find-my-r-libraries-on-install)

Answer (score 0):

R や Python を実際に使っているわけでは無いので少し調べた程度ですが、
一般的には環境変数 PATH 等を使いコマンドのインストール先を指定しています。

**参考:**
[PythonからRを使う](https://kaisk.hatenadiary.com/entry/2014/03/18/160203)

> rpy2経由でPythonからRにアクセスします。
> 環境変数の設定が必要でしたが、これはどれが実際に必要なのかちょっとわかりません。
> 特に害があるわけではないのでとりあえず設定しておけばいいと思います。
>
> - PATH変数にR.dllが含まれるディレクトリを追加
> - R_HOME変数を新設してRのワーキングスペースのディレクトリを追加
> - R_USER変数を新設してユーザネームを追加

環境変数の設定や確認方法は非常に一般的な話なので、ご自身で調べて頂くか、以下の投稿も参考にしてください。(言語は違いますが "Windows における環境変数の設定方法" という意味では応用が効くはずです)

[Laravelが使うphpの指定方法](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/77927)